# Firebase hosting not recognising next.js index page

Tags: firebase, next.js

We have picked up a very messy half built project and are trying to get it into an external beta testing state...

It is a next.js application which works fine if we run `npm run build` and then `npm run start`.

We prefer to host it on Firebase, for all the normal reasons and I believe it should be possible to do so.

However, when we install firebase and enable `firebase experiments:enable webframeworks` and `firebase init hosting` and accept the default options (Y,N) it adds the standard firebase index.html to the public folder - even though it didn't ask if we wanted that...

If we leave that index.html in place in the public folder then run `firebase serve` or `firebase deploy`, the /public/index.html is delivered as the root page of our site. When it should be the Index of the next application. If we delete the firebase index.html, and then rerun firebase serve to rebuild, then we get an 'undefined url' error (as it can't find the /public/index.html presumably).

We have an index.tsx in the /pages dir and when we run firebase serve, the build process does seem to be placing index-xxxxx.js chunk files etc. in .firebase/sitename/hosting/_next/static/chunks/pages.

We have tried adding rewrites in the firebase.json of various sorts, changed versions, everything we can think of. But still can't work out why firebase is not recognising the site root index page when it is running just fine on npm run start.

Any help appreciated to help us troubleshoot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you ever found an answer to this?

Comment: Not yet @KirályRoland! I've seen a few people implying that only 'code' questions are valid on Stackoverflow nowadays. Which is obviously not correct. There is no way we could just dump hundreds of lines of spaghetti code up to get people to pick through it. But we suspect the messed up code's Middleware isn't compatible with FB hosting. We are doing a complete rewrite at some point without the middleware (if we can) and see what happens. Ended up having to use Vercel in the end. Which is OK. But not as good a dev experience as FB. And more expensive. Hope this helps give a few clues! Szía!